# Executing the assembly generated by Numba

Tags: python, assembly, linker, numba

In a bizarre turn of events, I've ended up in the following predicament where I'm using the following Python code to write the assembly generated by Numba to a file:

```py
@jit(nopython=True, nogil=True)
def six():
    return 6

with open("six.asm", "w") as f:
    for k, v in six.inspect_asm().items():
        f.write(v)
```

The assembly code is successfully written to the file but I can't figure out how to execute it. I've tried the following:

```sh
$ as -o six.o six.asm
$ ld six.o -o six.bin
$ chmod +x six.bin
$ ./six.bin
```

However, the linking step fails with the following:

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000004000f0
six.o: In function `cpython::__main__::six$241':
<string>:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `PyArg_UnpackTuple'
<string>:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `PyEval_SaveThread'
<string>:(.text+0x53): undefined reference to `PyEval_RestoreThread'
<string>:(.text+0x62): undefined reference to `PyLong_FromLongLong'
<string>:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `PyExc_RuntimeError'
<string>:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `PyErr_SetString'
```

I'm suspecting that the Numba and/or the Python standard library need to be dynamically linked against the generated object file for this to run successfully but I'm not sure how it can be done (if it can even be done in the first place).

I've also tried the following where I write the intermediate LLVM code to the file instead of the assembly:

```py
with open("six.ll", "w") as f:
    for k, v in six.inspect_llvm().items():
        f.write(v)
```

And then

```sh
$ lli six.ll
```

But this fails as well with the following error:

```
'main' function not found in module.
```

**UPDATE:**

It turns out that there exists a utility to find the relevant flags to pass to the `ld` command to dynamically link the Python standard library.

```sh
$ python3-config --ldflags
```

Returns

```
-L/Users/rayan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-darwin -lpython3.7m -ldl -framework CoreFoundation
```

Running the following again, this time with the correct flags:

```sh
$ as -o six.o six.asm
$ ld six.o -o six.bin -L/Users/rayan/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-darwin -lpython3.7m -ldl -framework CoreFoundation 
$ chmod +x six.bin
$ ./six.bin
```

I am now getting

```
ld: warning: No version-min specified on command line
ld: entry point (_main) undefined. for inferred architecture x86_64
```

I have tried adding a `_main` label in the assembly file but that doesn't seem to do anything. Any ideas on how to define the entry point?

**UPDATE 2:**

Here's the assembly code in case that's useful, it seems like the target function is the one with label `_ZN8__main__7six$241E`:

```
    .text
    .file   "<string>"
    .globl  _ZN8__main__7six$241E
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   _ZN8__main__7six$241E,@function
_ZN8__main__7six$241E:
    movq    $6, (%rdi)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    retq
.Lfunc_end0:
    .size   _ZN8__main__7six$241E, .Lfunc_end0-_ZN8__main__7six$241E

    .globl  _ZN7cpython8__main__7six$241E
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   _ZN7cpython8__main__7six$241E,@function
_ZN7cpython8__main__7six$241E:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rax
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movq    %rsi, %rdi
    movabsq $.const.six, %rsi
    movabsq $PyArg_UnpackTuple, %r8
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    callq   *%r8
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .LBB1_3
    movabsq $_ZN08NumbaEnv8__main__7six$241E, %rax
    cmpq    $0, (%rax)
    je  .LBB1_2
    movabsq $PyEval_SaveThread, %rax
    callq   *%rax
    movabsq $PyEval_RestoreThread, %rcx
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   *%rcx
    movabsq $PyLong_FromLongLong, %rax
    movl    $6, %edi
    popq    %rcx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    jmpq    *%rax
.LBB1_2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movabsq $PyExc_RuntimeError, %rdi
    movabsq $".const.missing Environment", %rsi
    movabsq $PyErr_SetString, %rax
    callq   *%rax
.LBB1_3:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rcx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    retq
.Lfunc_end1:
    .size   _ZN7cpython8__main__7six$241E, .Lfunc_end1-_ZN7cpython8__main__7six$241E
    .cfi_endproc

    .globl  cfunc._ZN8__main__7six$241E
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   cfunc._ZN8__main__7six$241E,@function
cfunc._ZN8__main__7six$241E:
    movl    $6, %eax
    retq
.Lfunc_end2:
    .size   cfunc._ZN8__main__7six$241E, .Lfunc_end2-cfunc._ZN8__main__7six$241E

    .type   _ZN08NumbaEnv8__main__7six$241E,@object
    .comm   _ZN08NumbaEnv8__main__7six$241E,8,8
    .type   .const.six,@object
    .section    .rodata,"a",@progbits
.const.six:
    .asciz  "six"
    .size   .const.six, 4

    .type   ".const.missing Environment",@object
    .p2align    4
.const.missing Environment:
    .asciz  "missing Environment"
    .size   ".const.missing Environment", 20


    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

Comment: Can I just ask _how_ you ended up needing to do this? :D

Comment: @AKX Long story short, I'm trying to distribute computations by distributing chunks of assembly

Comment: That sounds hazardous and fraught with corner cases, I must admit.

Comment: Linking the .asm file with a stub .c file only gets me (macOS) a dyld error... `dyld: BIND_OPCODE_SET_SEGMENT_AND_OFFSET_ULEB has segment 1 which is not writable in /Users/akx/build/so61678226/./six`

Comment: I guess you get an object file as opposed to an executable file. Running a linker (`ld`) may do the job, e.g.: `as six.asm -o six.o; ld six.o -o six.bin; ./six.bin`

Comment: @AlexDenisov running the linker on six.o results in a bunch of undefined references so I'm guessing the main issue here is locating the Numba object files and including them in the ```ld``` call. Do you happen to know anything about that?

Comment: @RayanHatout not really. On my machine (mac) it's at `/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib`, on Linux I'd just expect it to be somewhere around `/usr/lib`. But this won't be sufficient since the code you have is missing the `main`/`start` function, so you'd have to write some sort of a driver in C that calls the `inspect_asm`-generated machine code. I'd suggest also asking this on the numba mailing list/forum (I'm not familiar with this ecosystem).

Comment: Can I ask what kinds of computations you're doing? If you're just trying to make something run in parallel, Numba has a parallel option, and there may be other libraries that could help too (e.g., Pytorch, Dask). Otherwise, if you just want more low level control, why not reach for something like Cython, or a lower level language like C or Rust? or maybe Go or Julia? Forgive me, I'm just in disbelief

Comment: @bug_spray I'm not doing any specific computation, this is all just some quarantine side project. The end goal is to create a python package that provides a high-level interface to seamlessly distribute computations

Comment: You are getting the `main not defined` error because you need an entry point. What `numba` does is, it generates the `asm`, then wraps it with `ctypes`-- so numba doesn't need to define main there. Long story short, without and entry point your `asm` is useless unless you wrap it with `ctypes`, or you do something like link it with C program that has a entry point (`main`).

Comment: Oh yeah, wild guess, but I think you are using Windows. That is why you are getting those `Py... undefined errors`. Never tried it, but you could try linking your `asm` with `Python.h` and all those other things.

Comment: @Xilpex The Py... undefined errors have been fixed already and it was actually on MacOS, not Windows. Thanks for the ```ctypes``` proposition, I'll try that at some point.

Comment: I have no clue if this would work, but you could try making a function named `main` then JITing that.

Comment: Hah I actually did try to do that. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Could you paste all the code? [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I guess you already tried using `-e _ZN7cpython8__main__7six$241E` or `-e _ZN8__main__7six$241E` with `ld`?

Comment: @MargaretBloom - I tried that. Led to another error.

Comment: Thank you. What about the rest of the *Pyrhon* code (*sum* is missing). And a full command list that you're invoking (including *python*).

Comment: @CristiFati ```sum``` was just a typo, it was supposed to be ```six``` i.e. the target function

Comment: Hmm, running the *Python* code I get an empty *.asm* file (on *Win*, or *Linux*), while running the assembler (*LLVM* or *GNU*) on the provided one yields errors.

Comment: The assembly code you posted does not look like a complete program.  Rather, it looks like a single function that can be used as a part of a program.   What do you expect to happen when you execute this code as a program?

Comment: As fuz said your assembly program isn't a complete program.  This should be surprising since the Python function `six` that the assembly is supposed to be generated from isn't a complete program either.  Whatever you're trying to do you're not going about it the right way, and you've chosen the wrong tools for the job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After browsing [[PyData.Numba]: Numba](https://numba.pydata.org) *doc*s, and some debugging, trial and error, I reached to a conclusion: it seems you're off the path to your quest (as was also pointed out in comments).

*Numba* converts *Python* code (functions) to machine code (for the obvious reason: speed). It does everything (convert, build, insert in the running process) on the fly, the programmer only needs to decorate the function as *e.g.* `@numba.jit` ([[PyData.Numba]: Just-in-Time compilation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/jit-compilation.html#just-in-time-compilation)).

The behavior that you're experiencing **is correct**. The *Dispatcher* object (used by decorating the *six* function) only generates (assembly) code for the function itself (it's no *main* there, as the code is executing in the current process (*Python* interpreter's *main* function)). So, it's normal for the linker to complain there's no *main* symbol. It's like writing a *C* file that only contains:

```c
int six()
{
    return 6;
}
```

In order for things to work properly, you have to:

1. Build the *.asm* file into an *.o* (object) file (done)
2. Include the *.o* file from *#1.* into a library which can be

   - Static
   - Dynamic

   The library is to be linked in the (final) executable. This step is optional as you could use the *.o* file directly
3. Build another file that defines *main* (and calls *six* - which I assume it's the whole purpose) into an *.o* file. As I'm not very comfortable with assembly, I wrote it in *C*
4. Link the 2 entities (from *#2.* (*#1.*) and *#3.*) together

As an alternative, you could take a look at [[PyData.Numba]: Compiling code ahead of time](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/pycc.html#compiling-code-ahead-of-time), but bear in mind that it would generate a *Python* (extension) module.

Back to the current problem. Did the test on *Ubuntu 18.04 064bit*.

- *code00.py*:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python

  import math
  import sys

  import numba


  @numba.jit(nopython=True, nogil=True)
  def six():
      return 6


  def main(*argv):
      six()  # Call the function(s), otherwise `inspect_asm()` would return empty dict
      speed_funcs = [
          (six, numba.int32()),
      ]
      for func, _ in speed_funcs:
          file_name_asm = "numba_{:s}_{:s}_{:03d}_{:02d}{:02d}{:02d}.asm".format(func.__name__, sys.platform, int(round(math.log2(sys.maxsize))) + 1, *sys.version_info[:3])
          asm = func.inspect_asm()
          print("Writing to {:s}:".format(file_name_asm))
          with open(file_name_asm, "wb") as fout:
              for k, v in asm.items():
                  print("    {:}".format(k))
                  fout.write(v.encode())


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                     64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
      rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
      print("\nDone.\n")
      sys.exit(rc)
  ```
- *main00.c*:

  ```c
  #include <dlfcn.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  //#define SYMBOL_SIX "_ZN8__main__7six$241E"
  #define SYMBOL_SIX "cfunc._ZN8__main__7six$241E"


  typedef int (*SixFuncPtr)();


  int main()
  {
      void *pMod = dlopen("./libnumba_six_linux.so", RTLD_LAZY);
      if (!pMod) {
          printf("Error (%s) loading module\n", dlerror());
          return -1;
      }
      SixFuncPtr pSixFunc = dlsym(pMod, SYMBOL_SIX);
      if (!pSixFunc) {
          printf("Error (%s) loading function\n", dlerror());
          dlclose(pMod);
          return -2;
      }
      printf("six() returned: %d\n", (*pSixFunc)());
      dlclose(pMod);
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- *build.sh*:

  ```bash
  #!/usr/bin/env bash

  CC=gcc

  LIB_BASE_NAME=numba_six_linux

  FLAG_LD_LIB_NUMBALINUX="-Wl,-L. -Wl,-l${LIB_BASE_NAME}"
  FLAG_LD_LIB_PYTHON="-Wl,-L/usr/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-lpython3.7m"

  rm -f *.asm *.o *.a *.so *.exe

  echo Generate .asm
  python3 code00.py

  echo Assemble
  as -o ${LIB_BASE_NAME}.o ${LIB_BASE_NAME}_064_030705.asm

  echo Link library
  LIB_NUMBA="./lib${LIB_BASE_NAME}.so"
  #ar -scr ${LIB_NUMBA} ${LIB_BASE_NAME}.o
  ${CC} -o ${LIB_NUMBA} -shared ${LIB_BASE_NAME}.o ${FLAG_LD_LIB_PYTHON}

  echo Dump library contents
  nm -S ${LIB_NUMBA}
  #objdump -t ${LIB_NUMBA}

  echo Compile and link executable
  ${CC} -o main00.exe main00.c -ldl

  echo Exit script
  ```

**Output**:

> ```
> (py_venv_pc064_03.07.05_test0) [cfati@cfati-ubtu-18-064-00:~/Work/Dev/StackOverflow/q061678226]> ~/sopr.sh
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> build.sh  code00.py  main00.c
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> ./build.sh
> Generate .asm
> Python 3.7.5 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:50:52) [GCC 8.3.0] 064bit on linux
>
> Writing to numba_six_linux_064_030705.asm:
>     ()
>
> Done.
>
> Assemble
> Link library
> Dump library contents
> 0000000000201020 B __bss_start
> 00000000000008b0 0000000000000006 T cfunc._ZN8__main__7six$241E
> 0000000000201020 0000000000000001 b completed.7698
> 00000000000008e0 0000000000000014 r .const.missing Environment
> 00000000000008d0 0000000000000004 r .const.six
>                  w __cxa_finalize
> 0000000000000730 t deregister_tm_clones
> 00000000000007c0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
> 0000000000200e58 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
> 0000000000201018 d __dso_handle
> 0000000000200e60 d _DYNAMIC
> 0000000000201020 D _edata
> 0000000000201030 B _end
> 00000000000008b8 T _fini
> 0000000000000800 t frame_dummy
> 0000000000200e50 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
> 0000000000000990 r __FRAME_END__
> 0000000000201000 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
>                  w __gmon_start__
> 00000000000008f4 r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
> 00000000000006f0 T _init
>                  w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
>                  w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
>                  U PyArg_UnpackTuple
>                  U PyErr_SetString
>                  U PyEval_RestoreThread
>                  U PyEval_SaveThread
>                  U PyExc_RuntimeError
>                  U PyLong_FromLongLong
> 0000000000000770 t register_tm_clones
> 0000000000201020 d __TMC_END__
> 0000000000201028 0000000000000008 B _ZN08NumbaEnv8__main__7six$241E
> 0000000000000820 0000000000000086 T _ZN7cpython8__main__7six$241E
> 0000000000000810 000000000000000a T _ZN8__main__7six$241E
> Compile and link executable
> Exit script
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> build.sh  code00.py  libnumba_six_linux.so  main00.c  main00.exe  numba_six_linux_064_030705.asm  numba_six_linux.o
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> # Run the executable
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> ./main00.exe
> six() returned: 6
> [064bit prompt]>
> ```

Also posting (since it's important) *numba_six_linux_064_030705.asm*:

```
    .text
    .file   "<string>"
    .globl  _ZN8__main__7six$241E
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   _ZN8__main__7six$241E,@function
_ZN8__main__7six$241E:
    movq    $6, (%rdi)
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    retq
.Lfunc_end0:
    .size   _ZN8__main__7six$241E, .Lfunc_end0-_ZN8__main__7six$241E

    .globl  _ZN7cpython8__main__7six$241E
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   _ZN7cpython8__main__7six$241E,@function
_ZN7cpython8__main__7six$241E:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rax
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movq    %rsi, %rdi
    movabsq $.const.six, %rsi
    movabsq $PyArg_UnpackTuple, %r8
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    callq   *%r8
    testl   %eax, %eax
    je  .LBB1_3
    movabsq $_ZN08NumbaEnv8__main__7six$241E, %rax
    cmpq    $0, (%rax)
    je  .LBB1_2
    movabsq $PyEval_SaveThread, %rax
    callq   *%rax
    movabsq $PyEval_RestoreThread, %rcx
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    callq   *%rcx
    movabsq $PyLong_FromLongLong, %rax
    movl    $6, %edi
    popq    %rcx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    jmpq    *%rax
.LBB1_2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movabsq $PyExc_RuntimeError, %rdi
    movabsq $".const.missing Environment", %rsi
    movabsq $PyErr_SetString, %rax
    callq   *%rax
.LBB1_3:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    popq    %rcx
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    retq
.Lfunc_end1:
    .size   _ZN7cpython8__main__7six$241E, .Lfunc_end1-_ZN7cpython8__main__7six$241E
    .cfi_endproc

    .globl  cfunc._ZN8__main__7six$241E
    .p2align    4, 0x90
    .type   cfunc._ZN8__main__7six$241E,@function
cfunc._ZN8__main__7six$241E:
    movl    $6, %eax
    retq
.Lfunc_end2:
    .size   cfunc._ZN8__main__7six$241E, .Lfunc_end2-cfunc._ZN8__main__7six$241E

    .type   _ZN08NumbaEnv8__main__7six$241E,@object
    .comm   _ZN08NumbaEnv8__main__7six$241E,8,8
    .type   .const.six,@object
    .section    .rodata,"a",@progbits
.const.six:
    .asciz  "six"
    .size   .const.six, 4

    .type   ".const.missing Environment",@object
    .p2align    4
".const.missing Environment":
    .asciz  "missing Environment"
    .size   ".const.missing Environment", 20


    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```

**Notes**:

- *numba_six_linux_064_030705.asm* (and everything that derives from it) contain the code for the *six* function. Actually, there are a bunch of symbols (on *OSX*, you can also use the native `otool -T`) like:

  1. ***cfunc._ZN8__main__7six$241E*** - the (*C*) function itself
  2. *_ZN7cpython8__main__7six$241E* - the *Python* wrapper:

     2.1. Performs the *C* <=> *Python* conversions (via *Python API* functions like *PyArg_UnpackTuple*)

     2.2. Due to *#1.* it needs (depends on) *libpython3.7m*

     2.3. As a consequence, `nopython=True` has no effect in this case

  Also, the *main* part from these symbols doesn't refer to an executable entry point (*main* function), but to a ***Python* module's top level namespace (*__main__*)**. After all, this code is supposed to be run from *Python*
- Due to the fact that the *C* plain function contains a *dot* (***.***) in the name, I couldn't call it directly from *C* (as it's an invalid identifier name), so I had to **load** (the *.so* and) **the function manually** (*DlOpen* / *DlSym*), resulting in more code than simply calling the function.
  I didn't try it, but I think it would make sense that the following (manual) changes to the generated *.asm* file would simplify the work:

  - Renaming the plain *C* function name (to something like *__six*, or any other valid *C* identifier that also doesn't clash with another (explicit or internal) name) in the *.asm* file before assembling it, would make the function directly callable from *C*
  - Removing the *Python* wrapper (*#2.*) would also get rid of *#2.2.*

---

#### Update *#0*

Thanks to @PeterCordes, who shared that exact piece of info ([[GNU.GCC]: Controlling Names Used in Assembler Code](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html)) that I was missing, here's a much simpler version.

*main01.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

extern int six() asm ("cfunc._ZN8__main__7six$241E");

int main()
{
    printf("six() returned: %d\n", six());
}
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [064bit prompt]> # Resume from previous point + main01.c
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> build.sh  code00.py  libnumba_six_linux.so  main00.c  main00.exe  main01.c  numba_six_linux_064_030705.asm  numba_six_linux.o
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> ar -scr libnumba_six_linux.a numba_six_linux.o
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> gcc -o main01.exe main01.c ./libnumba_six_linux.a -Wl,-L/usr/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,-lpython3.7m
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> ls
> build.sh  code00.py  libnumba_six_linux.a  libnumba_six_linux.so  main00.c  main00.exe  main01.c  main01.exe  numba_six_linux_064_030705.asm  numba_six_linux.o
> [064bit prompt]>
> [064bit prompt]> ./main01.exe
> six() returned: 6
> [064bit prompt]>
> ```

Comment: GNU C extensions can work around the `.` in the asm name: declare it as `void foo(stuff) asm("foo.bar")` to set the asm symbol name separately from the normal rules: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html.  Should work with GCC/clang/ICC.  Or yes, changing the asm source file to replace `foo.bar` with `foo_bar` everywhere should work, too.  (Not just on the label, also on the `.globl foo.bar` directive and other references.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: I searched for something like this for about an hour! Trying it. Thanks!!! :)

Comment: Note that the symbols that start with `_Z` are mangled following the GNU C++ ABI conventions.  For example `_ZN7cpython8__main__7six$241E` demangles to `cpython::__main__::six$241`.  There's still a dollar sign ($) in the identifier but at least some C++ compilers allow it as an extension. btw. please don't create "update" or "edit" sections, just incorporate your additions and corrections into your posts as if they were always there. Anyone who want to see how your post changed can view the edit history.

Comment: Kind of surprised it works without initialized Python interpreter, would expect to get problems eventually without it.

Comment: @ead: Not really. I called the simple *C* function (if you look at the assembly it's only 3 instructions long). So no *Python API* functions are invoked, therefore no need for *Py\_Initialize\**.