# what is the way to convert a Python code into a DLL exportable code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, dllexport

I am on a Windows 10 platform. I want to use my Python code in another code. I know DLL is a way I can do that. But I have not found any way to convert a Python code to DLL. Can anybody please share there way to do what I want to achieve. Here is a sample code of Python:

```
import numpy as np

def test(abc): # abc is numpy array
    c = np.sum(abc)
    return c
```

Please let me know what I can do. If someone has example then it will be helpful.

Comment: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html

Comment: @CristiFati Please let me know what you mean by the above link? I cannot see an answer to my query.

Comment: Somewhere not very far from the beginning (in the "*Cython Hello World*" chapter), is this text: "*Which will leave a file in your local directory called helloworld.so in unix or helloworld.pyd in Windows. Now to use this file: start the python interpreter and simply import it as if it was a regular python module:*". It's as clear as it can get, meaning that this package does exactly what you need.

Comment: @CristiFati Thank you for clarification. But that is not the answer to my query.I want to have a DLL. I know DLL equivalent to PYD, but it is not useful in other program if required. It is only for Python.

Comment: Oh, so you need a "regular" *.dll* to be used outside *Python* (sorry for assuming the opposite :) ). Hmm, then maybe you could use *Numba*? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61678226/executing-the-assembly-generated-by-numba. You could also consider https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html.